# Xceed.WPF.Toolkit.MessageBox doesn't show

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, xceed

I've determined that:
There is a checkbox at the bottom of the page named "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"
If I un-tick this the issue goes away.
Has anyone else experienced this?
Are there any other know pitfalls to using WPF.ToolKit dialogs?

Comment: I wonder if there's a requirement beyond 4.0 Client Profile...      Turns out that WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMessageW(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWnd, int uMsgFilterMin, int uMsgFilterMax) + 0x16 bytes is hanging. Any Ideas, anyone?

Comment: OK, that was version 1.5. I've since seen it mysteriously work, then fail again after messing with project settings. XCeed.Wpf.Toolkit 2.0 has fixed the problem, but won't get my themed items out a resource dictionary.

Comment: And now 2.2.1 is doing it with .NET 4.0 full. I hope to find a solution and post it here

Comment: After totally reverting to XCeed.Wpf.Toolkit 2.0 (and rebooting, just in case) the problem persists. I'm switching back to System.Windows.MessageBox even though it doesn't match the application.